# compare rows from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table A and table B in SQL SERVER. I want to compare some columns of a row from each table and return the different values from table A.
How do I do it?

Example :

```
TABLE A
   columns : id txt1 txt2 txt3 
   values :   1  XY   XX  XXY



 TABLE B
  columns : id txt1 txt2 txt3 txt4
  values :  1  XZ   XX  XYZ    XXX
```

I want the result:

```
 TABLE A 
   txt1  txt3 
    XY   XXY
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

A SQL query returns a *fixed* set of columns.  So, you cannot do what you want.  Dynamic SQL doesn't even work because different rows might have a different set of columns.

You *could* do something like `NULL` out values that are the same:

```
select a.id,
       nullif(a.txt1, b.txt1) as txt1,
       nullif(a.txt2, b.txt2) as txt2,
       nullif(a.txt3, b.txt3) as txt3,
       nullif(a.txt4, b.txt4) as txt4
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Or list the names of columns that are different:

```
select a.id,
       concat_ws(',',
                 (case when a.txt1 = b.txt1 then 'txt1' end),
                 (case when a.txt2 = b.txt2 then 'txt2' end),
                 (case when a.txt3 = b.txt3 then 'txt3' end),
                 (case when a.txt4 = b.txt4 then 'txt4' end)
                )
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id;
```